# define proxy for pysetup

Tags: python, proxy, distutils

i'm trying to install a python package on RHEL5 (old i know).

```
[root@myhost~]# pysetup install shyaml
Checking the installation location...
Getting information about 'shyaml'...
extensions in requires.txt are not supported (used by u'pip' 6.0.6)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pysetup", line 5, in ?
    pkg_resources.run_script('Distutils2==1.0a4', 'pysetup')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 407, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1084, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Distutils2-1.0a4-py2.4.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/pysetup", line 4, in ?
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Distutils2-1.0a4-py2.4.egg/distutils2/run.py", line 651, in main
    return dispatcher()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Distutils2-1.0a4-py2.4.egg/distutils2/run.py", line 639, in __call__
    return func(self, self.args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Distutils2-1.0a4-py2.4.egg/distutils2/run.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Distutils2-1.0a4-py2.4.egg/distutils2/run.py", line 167, in _install
    return not install(target)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Distutils2-1.0a4-py2.4.egg/distutils2/install.py", line 515, in install
    info = get_infos(project)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Distutils2-1.0a4-py2.4.egg/distutils2/install.py", line 339, in get_infos
    release = index.get_release(requirements)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Distutils2-1.0a4-py2.4.egg/distutils2/pypi/wrapper.py", line 40, in decorator
    raise exception
socket.error: (101, 'Network is unreachable')
```

This is ok, because this host does not have access to the internet but has access via http proxy. But i can't find anything how to configure pysetup for http proxy.

I already tried exporting the proxy variables wget/curl style:

```
http_proxy=http://proxyhost:3128
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyhost:3128
https_proxy=http://proxyhost:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxyhost:3128
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try setting the proxy URL in environment variables, e.g. `http_proxy=http://proxy server.com:3128 pysetup install shyaml`

Comment: updated question concerning proxy env

Comment: Did you actually export those variables, or are they just defined as above (without export)? If not try `export http_proxy=http://proxyhost:3128` etc. Failing that you should be able to install the package by downloading and extracting it, then run `python setup.py install`.